# How to move an attribute inside an entity in Visual Studio data model designer?

Tags: .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, entity-framework, database-design

When I design a data model in Visual Studio, I can only add/remove/rename entity attributes. Is it possible to rearrange the fields already present (considering model-first process, meaning the database to be generated from the model after it is designed)?

Comment: What do you mean by rearrange?

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to do so is to edit your edmx as an xml file (right click>Open With>XML (Text) Editor), find the  pertaining to your entity in the csdl section of the file, and move the  tag of your property up and down as needed.

I don't know a method to get the same result through the designer only.

Comment: Yes, this seems to be the preferred way for now :( In designer, you can only cut+paste on the last position in the entity, which might be handy if you only want to move one or two properties.  See also: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/adodotnetentityframework/thread/a352a3eb-c7ab-4972-a6d5-a8e9f1d77bdc